# Vue3 - Pinia + Auth0 - isAuthenticated always false

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, auth0, pinia

I'm developing a vue3 app using pinia as state manager and auth0 as authprovider.

In my vue router, I've the following code to manage the authentication:

```js
router.beforeEach(async (to: RouteLocationNormalized, from: RouteLocationNormalized, next: NavigationGuardNext) => {
    const authStore = useAuthStore();
    const isLogged = authStore.isLogged();
    if (!isLogged) await handleNotLogged(to, from, next);
    else await handleLogged(to, from, next);
});

async function handleNotLogged(to: RouteLocationNormalized, from: RouteLocationNormalized, next: NavigationGuardNext) {
    const authStore = useAuthStore();
    if (to?.query?.code && to?.query?.state) {
        next({ name: '/logged/home' });
    } else {
        await authStore.login();
    }
}
async function handleLogged(to: RouteLocationNormalized, from: RouteLocationNormalized, next: NavigationGuardNext) {next()}
```

here is my authStore

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { User } from '@models/user';
import { useStorage } from '@vueuse/core';
import { RouteLocation } from 'vue-router';
import { createAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-vue';
const authService = createAuth0({
    domain: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_AUTH_URL,
    client_id: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_AUTH_CLIENT_ID,
    redirect_uri: `${window.location.origin}`,
});

const defaultUserData = {} as User;
const defaultLastRoute = { path: '/' } as RouteLocation;
export const useAuthStore = defineStore('AuthStore', {
    state: () => ({
        userData: useStorage('userData', defaultUserData, localStorage),
        lastRoute: useStorage('lastRoute', defaultLastRoute, localStorage),
        authService,
    }),
    actions: {
        isLogged(): boolean {
            try {
                return this.authService.isAuthenticated;
            } catch (error) {
                return false;
            }
        },
        async login(): Promise<boolean> {
            try {
                await this.authService.loginWithRedirect();
                return true;
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                return false;
            }
        },
        async logout(): Promise<boolean> {
            try {
                await this.authService.logout();
                return true;
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
                return false;
            }
        },
    },
});
```

And also my **main.ts**

```js
import App from './App.vue';
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';
import { registerPlugins } from '@plugins';
import { useAuthStore } from '@store/auth';
import router from '@router';
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';

async function main() {
    const app = createApp(App);
    registerPlugins();
    const pinia = createPinia();
    app.use(pinia);
    const authStore = useAuthStore();
    const { authService } = authStore;
    app.use(authService);
    app.use(router);
    app.use(vuetify).mount('#app');
}
main();
```

The problem is that everytime the beforeEach is triggered, the auth0 isAuthenticated returns false. Even when i've just succesfully logged.

I've searched for some answers, and some said that ewhen there is a code and state in query params we should call the auth0.handleRedirectCallback but there's a note in the method saying

> Note: The Auth0-Vue SDK handles this for you, unless you set skipRedirectCallback to true. In that case, be sure to explicitly call handleRedirectCallback yourself.

PS: The application in auth0 is configured as Single Page Application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create and register the Vue3-Auth0 component in the main.js/ts:

   ```
   import { createAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-vue";
   export const auth0 = createAuth0({...});
   app.use(auth0);
   ```
2. In the main component, verify if Auth0 is loading:

   ```
   <script setup>
     ...
     import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-vue";
     const { isLoading } = useAuth0();
     ...
   </script>
   <template>
     <router-view v-if="!isLoading"></router-view>
     <div v-else>Loading</div>
   </template>
   ```

If Auth0 is loading then isAuthenticated will be false.

Comment: Sorry for taking this long to answer, but the project that I was working with it was on hold. 
I've tried your approach but unfortunally it keeps loading forever

Comment: Yes this is the right way to use it. But I had to change my app.vue to be more likely yours. 
Then in my routes I defined a component that wraps the application layout

Answer (score 0):

There is already a topic with this question answered, I believe this one can help you:
[Auth0 isAuthenticated() is always false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72599560/auth0-isauthenticated-is-always-false)

Comment: Hello Matheus. Thanks for answering. I didn't mentioned in the post, my mistake. But I've already tried this approach. But didn't work aswell

Comment: I saw in some places people commenting on The solution was in app Settings in Auth0." Change Application Type from Web App to SPA app", have you tried this?

Comment: Yes, i've said that in the **PS** hehehe

Comment: you have a complex case, I hope it's not the same problem a guy had with react on this blog https://community.auth0.com/t/isauthenticated-fails-on-login-works-on-refresh/42515/17. 
I know it's not the answer, but did you even read this? https://auth0.com/blog/complete-guide-to-vue-user-authentication/

Comment: On the blog link I sent you, look at this answer :isAuthenticated only works after handleRedirectCallback has been called, yet the isAuthenticated$ stream is public and open to be subscribed to immediately on app load, before handleRedirectCallback is complete. So everything subscribes to that stream on app load, gets a “false” result because handleRedirectCallback isn’t complete, and then once its complete all those observables have already completed and don’t re-poll for the new value.

Comment: the problem is that handleRedirectCallback returns invalidState